# PHP move uploaded file always error

Tags: php

I post a file by HTML and I want to move it but it always return value false.
here's my code :

```
$fileName = $_FILES['atc']['name'];
$fileTmp = $_FILES['atc']['tmp_name'];

$newDir = "/home/goes/attachments/" . $fileName;

$a = move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $newDir);

if ($a==true){
 echo "true";
}

else{
 echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the contents of your fields and the directory variable? It looks like at least one of the two directories isn't found.

Comment: have you checked that your form is set to use multipart encoding?

Comment: Try `$newDir = getcwd()."/home/goes/attachments/" . $fileName;`

Comment: Have you checked the file is actually uploaded `var_dump($_FILES);` Also have you checked you have permission to write to the folder?

Comment: yes my form encoding is multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the content of all of your variables, see if they contain anything (good)
2. Check if the directory where you want to place the files exists, and is writeable by the webserver (or whoever runs the PHP process).
3. Is this the script you are calling from your form? Apache only holds the uploaded files for the duration of the called script, after that, the files are deleted if they are not handled by the script.

Comment: hmm yeah, the file is stored to /tmp/ folder, am I need to change the permission first of tmp folder ?

Comment: The /tmp/ folder is the temporary folder of the webserver, it will have the right permissions there most probably. It's the permission of /home/goes/attachments/ that you need to check.

Answer (score 1):

The destination folder may not be have write permission

Answer (score 0):

foreach ($_FILES['atc']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){ 
$path = "home/goes/attachments/" . $fileName";
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path);
    }